# PHP top down code generator IDE

Tags: php, ide, code-generation

I know it is not strictly programming but is quite important for productivity when working OO design.

Is there any editor/IDE for php that allow to generate classes and operations of classes on demand?

This is, just like the codeassist of visual estudio for c++, eclipse with jave or the "control+shift+1" from flash develop for as3?

I mean just this:

------------IM IN A CLASS-----------

aNotYetCreatedClass.newOperation()

---

So with a click or combination over the work "aNotYetCreatedClass" it will be nice to ask to "create a new class" option.
The same applies to "newOperation()"

Thanks in advance for any help.
I've tried, zend, pdt eclipse, php storm, php designer... and on and on...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying with IDE try the UML tools like Visual Paradigm, its has the option to Instant code generation from Class Diagram and it'll support for popular programming languages:

- Java
- VB.NET
- Objective-C
- Ruby
- C#
- PHP
- ActionScript
- C++
- and more

http://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpumluserguide/276/330/7341_instantgener.html